# How to select and export individual bookmarks and/or bookmark folders from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, export

There is not easy way to export particular bookmarks - folders or individual bookmarks - from Google Chrome.

Is there are an easy way to do that without exporting everything to a text/html file and then manually removing the entries or scripting it?

Answer (score 2):

I found this Chrome extension that does a pretty decent job by allowing you to check-mark and export:

1. Entire folders
2. Individual bookmarks

[Export Selective Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-selective-bookmark/ahgbiciilcpclcekhegbhofljoolnfei/related)

[Example - select folders and individual bookmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF5Gr.png)